# Findstr does not work with SET /P?

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I have a batch file with a portion shown below:

```
    rem @echo off
    cd C:\Program Files\CA\AllFusion Gen\GEN\test8.ief\c\
    FINDSTR /C:"'V1600 OPER'"  /C:"'V1714 OPER'" /C:"'V1801 OPER'" /C:"'V1901 OPER'" "MPOAD10C"
```

The above batch file runs successfully with the above code. However, when I modified the script so that the user can enter two variables, as shown below **(%path%=test8.ief,%file_name%=MPOAD10C)**, it throws the following error:

'FINDSTR' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

```
    rem @echo off
    SET /P path=Enter name of IEF folder:
    echo. && echo.
    SET /P file_name=Enter name of file:
    echo. && echo.
    cd C:\Program Files\CA\AllFusion Gen\GEN\%path%\c
    FINDSTR /C:"'V1600 OPER'" /C:"'V1714 OPER'" /C:"'R18 V1801 OPER'" /C:"'V1901 OPER'" "%file_name%"
```

I have also entered the value "C:\WINDOWS\system32" in the PATH variable in the Environment Variables.

I am very new to batch scripting. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Mohit Gupta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `path` as one of your own variables, that particular environment variable is used by Windows to locate executable files, such as `findstr` as you've just discovered.

Change it to something like `mypath` and your problem should disappear.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this, use a name other than `%PATH%` to capture the user's input.

`%PATH%` is a special variable that controls [where the command interpreter searches for executables](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html). When you modify `%PATH%` with your `SET /P`, you change where the command interpreter will look for `FINDSTR`. It cannot find `FINDSTR.EXE` in the new location in `%PATH%`, hence the error that "'FINDSTR' is not recognized as an internal or external command"