# FINDSTR' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: cmd, jmeter

Hello I trying to install jmeter 
I type

```
cd C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin>jmeter.bat
```

And i receive this message

```
FINDSTR' is not recognized as an internal or external command
Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation
```

.
I trying change PATH variable , fallow this topic 
[Findstr does not work with SET /P?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901077/findstr-does-not-work-with-set-p)
, but it didn't work.
 My PATH user variable is `C:\Windows\System32, C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3\src\bin` and System variable is `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin; C:\WINDOWS\system32, C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin`

Please help i not find helpful information in google

Comment: Are the commas in path variables a typo error? If not, they should be replaced by `;`

Comment: I don't belive how stupid mistake i take. Thank you very much , how can i add you some reputation points?

Comment: Sorry Jordi in second line i had a java error i thinking it could be helpful

Comment: I think another problem is that your .bat file is looking for FINDSTR' with an apostrophe which of course doesn't exist as its name is FINDSTR without an apostrophe.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou it's a citation/quotation typo mistake only:  `'findstr' is not recognized ...`; _MC ND_ is right.

Comment: Problem solved by semicollons

Comment: @MCND you should answer this question, or your comment should be promoted to a answer

Comment: @cajuuh, from my point of view the question should be closed as off-topic. It is more a typo error than a programming problem.

Comment: @MCND all right, agree, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is trying to compute Java version using :

> java -v

And using findstr function on it.

But I guess that Java is not in path as you path is misconfigured.

So add Java bin folder to path and ensure you use ';' instead of ',' as separator.