# Running Jmeter gives 'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to open Jmeter by the batch file but it gives me a error like this:

```
'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation.
errorlevel=2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please don't post text as screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. I have done this for you in this question.

Comment: Do you have Java installed?

Comment: If java is installed, check your PATH environment variable. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266360/findstr-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command suggestions too.

Answer (score 16):

Right Click on My Computer, then click Properties, followed by Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables
Look for the Path System Variable
Add this path to the end, after a semicolon: C:\Windows\System32

Comment: This was the solution for me.

Answer (score 6):

Please Run Jmeter batch file as administrator

Answer (score 4):

1.Browse to C:\Windows\System32 and search "findstr" file. 
2. Copy and paste the "findstr" file in the bin folder of Jmeter 
(i.e) the path **C:.....\apache-jmeter-3.3\apache-jmeter-3.3\bin**  
3. Then try to run the **"jmeterw"** or the **"jmeter"** bat file , it should work fine.