# unable to run sbt in my windows 10 -64

Tags: scala, sbt

am getting below error when i run `sbt` in my command prompt

```html
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
FINDSTR: Cannot open C:\Users\vinoli\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin\out.txt
FINDSTR: Cannot open C:\Users\vinoli\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin\out.txt
FINDSTR: Cannot open C:\Users\vinoli\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin\out.txt
FINDSTR: Cannot open C:\Users\vinoli\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin\out.txt
FINDSTR: Cannot open C:\Users\vinoli\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin\out.txt

The java installation you have is not up to date
sbt requires at least version 1.6+, you have
version 0

Please go to http://www.java.com/getjava/ and download
a valid Java Runtime and install before running sbt.

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.15  (this may take some time)...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/launcher-interface/1.0.1/launcher-interface-1.0.1.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/template-resolver/0.1/template-resolver-0.1.jar ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#launcher-interface;1.0.1!launcher-interface.jar: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect (3358ms)

                [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#launcher-interface;1.0.1!launcher-interface.jar:  (0ms)

        ==== local: tried

          C:\Users\vinoli\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\launcher-interface\1.0.1\jars\launcher-interface.jar

        ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried

          file:/C:/Users/vinoli/.sbt/preloaded/org.scala-sbt/launcher-interface/1.0.1/jars/launcher-interface.jar

        ==== local-preloaded: tried

          file:/C:/Users/vinoli/.sbt/preloaded/org/scala-sbt/launcher-interface/1.0.1/launcher-interface-1.0.1.jar

        ==== Maven Central: tried

          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/launcher-interface/1.0.1/launcher-interface-1.0.1.jar

        ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

          https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/launcher-interface/1.0.1/jars/launcher-interface.jar

        ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

          https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/launcher-interface/1.0.1/jars/launcher-interface.jar

                [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#template-resolver;0.1!template-resolver.jar: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect (2316ms)

                [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#template-resolver;0.1!template-resolver.jar:  (0ms)

        ==== local: tried

          C:\Users\vinoli\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\template-resolver\0.1\jars\template-resolver.jar

        ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried

          file:/C:/Users/vinoli/.sbt/preloaded/org.scala-sbt/template-resolver/0.1/jars/template-resolver.jar

        ==== local-preloaded: tried

          file:/C:/Users/vinoli/.sbt/preloaded/org/scala-sbt/template-resolver/0.1/template-resolver-0.1.jar

        ==== Maven Central: tried

          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/template-resolver/0.1/template-resolver-0.1.jar

        ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

          https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/template-resolver/0.1/jars/template-resolver.jar

        ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

          https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/template-resolver/0.1/jars/template-resolver.jar

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

                :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: org.scala-sbt#launcher-interface;1.0.1!launcher-interface.jar

                :: org.scala-sbt#template-resolver;0.1!template-resolver.jar

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
download failed: org.scala-sbt#launcher-interface;1.0.1!launcher-interface.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#template-resolver;0.1!template-resolver.jar
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see C:\Users\vinoli\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.15
```

when i try to download java from http://java.com/getjava - its not even downloading .

can some one point out , what am i doing wrong here?

i use windows 10 -64 (fresh laptop)
installed jdk 1.8

Comment: Install latest java version and then try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... I found the issue...(my mistake actually)

I removed the sbt installed path (c:/programfiles/sbt/bin) which i added in the TMP environment variable. After removing (c:/programfiles/sbt/bin) from TMP, it worked.

thanks everyone for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

The message you get is misleading. I also had the same issue, although sbt worked fine till yesterday, I encountered the same message today.
After some search I came up to the answer below which indicates that something is wrong with your PATH env. variable.

[Running Jmeter gives 'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998250/running-jmeter-gives-findstr-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comm)

Right Click on My Computer, then click Properties, followed by Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables Look for the Path System Variable Add this path to the end, after a semicolon: C:\Windows\System32